# c# SQL Compact Monitoring FileSystemWatcher or SqlDependency

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I'm building an application that needs to monitor / accesses a SQL Compact database that gets created and modified by another standalone application.

What's the easiest way to do this? 
Does `SqlDependency` work with SQL Compact or should I use `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor the .sdf file for changes and then query for the last insertion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to start with FSW, and if that does not work (gives too many events), I have a (more complicated) solution (think SqlDependency light)

Comment: As I do have this very problem (FSW giving way too many events) I wonder what your "SqlDependency light" solution would have been.

Comment: It involved querying the system tables (INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES) for the number of rows in the primary key index, caching the result, and then comparing the cache with the current values on next "poll" to detect INSERTs